# add lists to dict by key

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, append, key

I have

```
symall={}  
for fc in range(0,4):  
    LoadGraphData(files[fc])  
    for tup in mn.symsel:  
        sb,sp,sr,sc,sv,sn = tup  
        symall{sb} = symall{sb}+sr
```

The fc loop gets data from files and puts result in mn.symsel
as `['abc',2,300,2,3,2]`,`['def',3,400,3,2,3]`, etc

I select out the key 'abc' and the 2nd value
and I need to build a dict such as

`symall{} = {['abc', 300,370,400,200,300],['def',400,.....`

the first iteration should add just `['abc',300]` to the dict
the 2nd iteration needs to append by the key 'abc' to get `['abc',300,370]`
etc.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid python syntax...

Answer (score 0):

### Solved my own problem using defaultdict.

Python 3.5
PyCharm IDE
Here is a more complete piece of code.
If there is a better way then that would be interesting.

```
from  collections import defaultdict
import selectval as mn


for fc in range(0,4):
    LoadRangeData(files[fc]) # gets [('ABCD',23.2),('DEFI',34.2)...
    for tup in mn.symsel:
       symin,sympr = tup
       symall += [(symin,sympr)]  # makes [('ABCD',23.2),('ABCD',33.2')
allsym = defaultdict(list)
for s,v in symall:            
    allsym[s].append(v)         # makes [('ABCD',23.2,33.2),...
```

works great